# I need to use an excel formula that takes a keyword in one column in order to extract full name of another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

What I am looking to do is write a formula that will use the keyword in Column B to search Column A and  extract the full text of Column A and copy it in Column C. Obviously the formula will be written in Column C to do that but I am having trouble figuring our what type of expression to use. I am assuming there might be some sort of combination of lookup, wildcard, and if statement. Any help would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please edit your question and add a sample of your data.

Comment: Hi @ReddyLutonadio I am unsure how to attach excel spreadsheet to question?

Comment: So what I am trying to do is query a list of names to see if the keyword from Column B is In Column A and if so I want to return the full text of column A

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the one cell rather than looking at the entire column you can try dragging down the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(FIND(B1,A1,1)),B1=""),"",A1)
```

or if you want it to not be case sensitive use:

```
=IF(OR(ISERROR(SEARCH(B1,A1,1)),B1=""),"",A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your example, in column B you have `Duck` which matches a word in **two** of the entries for Column A.

Perhaps you want to return both matches?

If so, and if you have Excel O365 with dynamic arrays and the `FILTER` function, you can use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($A$2:$A$5,ISNUMBER(FIND(B2,$A$2:$A$5))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Shown method works with any version of Excel.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `K181`:

  ```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(I181:I184,MATCH("* "&J181,I181:I184,0)),"")
  ```

**:Edited:**

*You may use this formula, in case Keyword is partial text (either at Beginning or middle or even last)*

[image]

- Formula in cell `L181`:

  ```
  =VLOOKUP("*"&J181&"*", I181:I186, 1, FALSE)
  ```
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*